# PHP Session set into variable and unset it.

Tags: php, session, cakephp

just a quick question.

I'm trying to store a session into a variable and then in the second line I try to unset the session. There after my variable become empty.

```
//Assuming session Hello has a value already

$hello_world = $this->Session->read('Hello');
$this->Session->delete('Hello');

print_r($hello_world); //empty here where it shouldn't ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the session variable with

```
$this->Session->delete('Hello');
```

SO the session variable with name `Hello` will be deleted from the session.See this [**LINK**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#SessionComponent%3a%3adelete)

Comment: i think, he wants to know "why $hello_world is empty" and not how to unset session variable

Comment: Ahhh my mistake, I thought the session was gone when the redirect went 404. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

try to echo the variable since it is not an array. if doesn't work then u have to post your whole view.